# Правильный путь настройки EntityFramework если один объект в двух и более таблицах

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Исторически сложилось что один из объектов системы находится в  двух таблицах имеющих связь один к одному.
Сейчас для работы с этим объектом используются два Entity объекта
Задача сделать 1 объект Entity таким образом, что бы при выполнении SaveChanges сохранялись изменения в обоих таблицах.
Рассматривается вариант сделать View на две таблицы для чтения а при сохранении и вызывать хранимую процедуру которая бы сохраняла все изменения.
Есть ли более "изящный" путь.

Comment: Более изящный путь - переделать бд.

Comment: Есть. Один-к-одному -- это "одна и та же таблица", это и более просто и более изящно. Если у вас нет реальной потребности в двух таблицах, то убирайте исторические костыли.

Comment: Потребность  есть . Это  куча написанного кода который нереально переделать в обозримое время.

Comment: А в чем суть проблемы? EF самостоятельно отслеживает изменения и сохранит всё что изменилось при SaveChanges. И да, лично я не вижу ничего плохого в использовании двух таблиц для хранения.

Comment: То есть вы имеете в виду надо настроить Entity для обновления нескольких таблиц из одной сущности?   Дайте пож ссылку на  Какие ни будь примеры.

Comment: Может, триггер?

Comment: @Евгения, что настроить? Это штатный функционал EF отслеживать все изменения сущностей и сохранять все изменения при вызове SaveChanges. Может быть вы приведете пример кода на котором у вас что-то не работает или работает не так как вы ожидаете?

Comment: Ах, вы хотите всё перенести в одину сущность? Да, так нельзя, но можно оставить вторую сущность в наличии, а в первой добавить *вычисляемые* свойства для изменения и получения данных, лежащих во второй сущности. У вас же есть навигационное свойство для связи 1:1, вот вы и можете написать что-то вроде `public int Prop { get => Entity2.Prop; set => Entity2.Prop = value; }`